# What are the APIs for hardware accelerated video decoding in phones?

Tags: ffmpeg, arm, decode, smartphone, hardware-acceleration

I have seen many smartphones coming with hardware accelerated video decoding supporting mpeg2 and h264, but unlike in desktop and laptop systems, it is not clear to me how to interact with the hardware acceleration.
For desktops/laptops there is DXVA, VDPAU and OpenMax.
Is any of those supported in Mobile phones? I think OpenMax is, but I am not sure of how widely supported it is.

Is anyone familiar with what is usually used to write hardware accelerated media players and decoders for platforms like Snapdragon, Tegra 2 or Omap 4 running Android or Windows Phone? 
I know that ffmpeg can be compiled for arm and I wonder what kind of hardware video acceleration it supports on that platform.

Comment: I have seen this kind of thing before and wouldnt be surprised if it is an sdk you have to purchase from the chip vendor (nvidia, etc).  Back in the day for example ARM had a fixed point MP3 decoder that they would sell, before an open source one could make real time performance.

Answer (score 1):

For ARMs, these are going to be vendor specific based on the silicon. I've seen some offer speedups by integrating subsets of the video decoding algorithms in hardware and you need to set up special registers to point to the data, flip a bit to go and wait for the output.

I think the majority of these though are going to be APIs to whatever embedded GPU is being used (Nvidia's Tegra, PowerVR SGX). I don't know a whole lot more about these, because they usually require NDAs and all you get is a header file and a ELF binary.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenGL ES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES) seems to be supported pretty much everywhere.